# bash aliases equivalent for powershell?

Tags: powershell

By default my Windows PowerShell starts in `C:\Users\Santosh`, my XAMPP installation is in `D:\` so the htdocs folder is located at `D:\xampp\htdocs`. If I have to edit something in htdocs folder then I have to type full `cd D:\xampp\htdocs\` *(autocompletion is not so kind)* then edit that file.

If this PowerShell were a Bash I would do this in .bash_aliases file:

`alias htdocs='cd D:\xampp\htdocs'`

Is it possible to maintain Bash aliases like file and alias any command in PowerShell?

Answer (score 18):

You want the **set-alias** commmand in coombination with a powershell script or a function. So open a editor and write:

```
set-location d:\xampp\htdocs
```

and save this file for example to *c:\Users\kumar\htdocs32.ps1* or you can create a function like this.

```
function htdocs32 { set-location d:\xampp\htdocs }
```

to execute scripts you must set the execution policy allowing scripts locally. open the powershell command line as administrator and type:

```
set-executionpolicy remotesigned
```

now you are able to set an alias for the powershell script:

```
set-alias htdocs c:\Users\kumar\htdocs32.ps1
```

and typing htdocs now will cd you into your htdocs folder

Powershell is using a *verb-noun* combination for the naming of so called cmdlets. *The verb referse to what you want to do and the noun with what you want to do something.*

To get help for the set-alias command you want to use:

```
get-help set-alias -full  |more
```

and no there is no less. the other method would be reading this http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee176958.aspx

Also to start off with power shell i recommend you to have a look at this url: http://www.powershellpro.com/powershell-tutorial-introduction/

To save the alias permanently you must save it in your users profile. first test whether a Profile is already in place using:

```
PS C:\> $profile
```

if you getting *false* you can create a new profile by typing:

```
 New-Item -path $profile -type file -force
```

now you can edit the file

```
c:\Users\kumar\Documents\WindowsPowerShell\Microsoft.PowerShell_profile.ps1
```

and put in the function definiton and an alias. as described above.

however setting an alias for this in linux is not neccessary. sicne there is a environmentvariable $CDPATH for bash which can be set in ~/.bahsrc .

Comment: Is there any file where these aliases are stored? It would be of great use if I backup it.

Comment: Getting `Cannot resolve alias 'htdocs' because it refers to term 'cd D:\xampp\htdocs', which is not recognized as a cmdlet, function, operable program, or script file. Verify the term and try again.` on doing `set-alias htdocs "cd D:\xampp\htdocs"`

Comment: ok you better write a ckdlet. open a texteditor and write: set-locaation c:\xampp\htdocs and save this file as htdocs32.ps1. assuming htdocs32.ps1 was saved in c:\Users\kumar\htdocs32.ps1 you can use set-alias htdocs c:\Users\kumars\htdocs32.ps1 . make sure you have set you execution policy accoringly.

Comment: @SantoshKumar Your solution requires the '/d' flag to change DRIVE then directory || "cd /d D:\xampp\htdocs"

Answer (score 2):

Actually you could try this, it will create a module loaded automatically.

Under C:\Users\kumar\Documents\WindowsPowerShell\

Create a new folder Modules,if not existing.

```
PS C:\>mkdir Modules
```

Under Modules create a folder call ex:"Quicky"

```
PS C:\>mkdir Quicky
```

Create a file called "quicky.psm1", .psm1 is the extension for Modules.

Edit the file and add that line.

```
function htdocs32 { set-location d:\xampp\htdocs }
```

Save the module.

Then simply call the function "htdocs32"

```
PS C:\>htdocs32
```

Answer (score 2):

Sometimes a `function` works better than an alias in PowerShell. Unlike the bash `alias`, Windows' `Set-Alias` expects single-word assignment, not a command string built up of several elements.

```
PS > function cal { bash -c cal }

PS > cal

     April 2023
Su Mo Tu We Th Fr Sa
                   1
 2  3  4  5  6  7  8
 9 10 11 12 13 14 15
16 17 18 19 20 21 22
23 24 25 26 27 28 29
30
```

Comment: Smart workaround!

Answer (score 0):

if you have not-too-restricted powershell script execution policy, you can just a script to do it.  Remember, unlike BASH, a Windows script **can** affect your shell after completion so you don't *need* an alias or bash function equivalent.

**htdocs.ps1**  (put this somewhere on your PATH, I'd go with **cdhtdocs.ps1** myself, but it's your naming convention)

```
chdir "d:\xampp\htdocs"
```

Note:  this **will** work to change drives as required too.  i.e. it would work if you were in **c:\temp\** to start with.

Answer (score 0):

I was struggling with this for a while and I've written this PowerShell module:

https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/HackF5.ProfileAlias

https://github.com/hackf5/powershell-profile-alias

To get started you install it by:

```
Install-Module HackF5.ProfileAlias
Register-ProfileAliasInProfile
```

Then use it like:

```
Set-ProfileAlias dkfeed 'Enter-Docker feed_app_container' -Bash
```

I've been using it for a while myself and I've found it fairly useful.

(It only runs on PS 7.0 as I wrote it for myself).

Comment: Please do not post the same answer to multiple questions. If the same information really answers both questions, then one question (usually the newer one) should be closed as a duplicate of the other. You can indicate this by [voting to close it as a duplicate](https://superuser.com/help/privileges/close-questions) or, if you don't have enough reputation for that, [raise a flag](https://superuser.com/help/privileges/flag-posts) to indicate that it's a duplicate. Otherwise tailor your answer to this question and don't just paste the same answer in multiple places.

Comment: Sorry dude, I've deleted the other post. I spent a bit of time on this one because it's a great feature in bash that I really missed. My only intention was to give other people a chance to try it out to see if it solved some of their problems.

Comment: This brief answer doesn't do justice to this awesome PowerShell module. Check out the https://github.com/hackf5/powershell-profile-alias/blob/master/README.md which goes more in-depth.