# Is there any way to create bash like aliases in windows (powershell or cmd)?

Tags: windows-10, powershell, cmd.exe

I want to create an alias that can still take input, like:

```
alias ytx='youtube-dl -ciw -f bestaudio --yes-playlist
```

Is this possible within windows?

I tried [bash aliases equivalent for powershell?](https://superuser.com/questions/516700/bash-aliases-equivalent-for-powershell) but it doesn't allow for input at the end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest approach, which works in any Windows version, is using common batch files, stored in a common folder available in your `PATH`.

For passing input to batch files, use `%*`, which evaluates to "all parameters passed to the batch file command line", or, use `%1`, `%2`, ... `%9` to refer to individual parameters.

Personally, I keep my batch files in `C:\Batch` and place it in the begining of my `PATH`. When running the batch files, you could omit the `.bat` suffix, to get a similar look-and-feel to bash aliases.

Few examples of my own:

- `s3cmd.bat`, which contains: `python c:\devtools\s3cmd-2.0.0\s3cmd %*`.
  All parameters are passed directly to the actual `s3cmd` program.
- `clangcheck.bat`, which is a shorthand for: 
  `clang-check -analyze -extra-arg -Xclang -extra-arg -analyzer-output=text %*`. Here, the batch parameters are passed along with extra arguments to `clang-check`.
- `epoch_to_time.bat`, which converts Unix epoch time to readable local time.
  It contains: `perl -pe "s/([\d]{10})/localtime $1/eg;" %1`. Here, `%1` is the epoch time to convert, which is expected as a single parameter.

Answer (score 0):

The equivalent command is the
[doskey command](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/doskey), which you may use as:

```
doskey ytx=youtube-dl -ciw -f bestaudio --yes-playlist $*
```

where `$*` represents all the parameters.

Here is a small example that echos its parameters:

[image]

Doskey can also be used in PowerShell. For more information see
[this answer](https://superuser.com/a/1362171/8672).

For making a doskey macro persistent across sessions, see the post
[Create permanent DOSKEY in Windows cmd](https://superuser.com/questions/1134368/create-permanent-doskey-in-windows-cmd).